# What programs are being used to design this?

Tags: adobe-photoshop

I'm new to design, and I often observe and have a lot of questions. I'm familiar with Photoshop, but I'm not sure of its full capabiilites. Take a look at this iPhone game called Cut the Rope, http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/cut-the-rope/id380293530?mt=8

I'm curious as to what program do they use to create these graphics and edit the colors. Is this just Photoshop and Illustrator or are there non-Adobe programs being used?

Comment: What about those graphics do you think can't be done in Photoshop?

Comment: note that for a game, there are going to be large numbers of things which are composited on the fly and shadows, bloom effects, etc are often rendered in real time. the game renderer itself can be said to be a graphics tool in this sense.

Comment: A good analogy there would be to think about layer effects in Photoshop. The actual png files you create are like the individual layers, while the shadows projected in the game are like applying a Drop Shadow to a layer in Photoshop.

Answer (score 6):

The bulk of that artwork was done with Illustrator or a similar vector drawing application. The pictorial bits (scenery, wood floors, etc) could easily have been done in Photoshop, less easily but quite feasibly in Illustrator.

There's nothing in the artwork itself that's outside the capabilities of Illustrator and Photoshop, which I think is the real answer you're looking for.

Answer (score 3):

You certainly could create those graphics in Photoshop and they probably did. However any 2D graphics tools will work, they're just drawings.

Some of the painterly background images look like they might have been done with a natural media tool like Alias Sketchbook, but that's just up to the individual artist.

Comment: It is possible this is an opengl application and they are actually 3d objects, but you are certainly correct that the textures used at the very least would be 2d raster images.

Comment: oh that is almost certainly true, but the term "3d object" is relative in this case and anyway of no concern to the artists.

Comment: ...a lot of "certainly"